# Is there a way to invoke MySQL's LOAD DATA INFILE programatically from NODE.js passing a stream?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Is there a way to pass a stream from a node.js process to MYSQL's LOAD DATA INFILE ?

In Postgres you can do this...

```
const dumpFile = fs.createReadStream(dumpFilePath);
const copyStatement = `copy "STAGING_TABLE" from STDIN`;
const stream = pgClient.query(copyFrom(copyStatement));
stream.on('end',function() {console.log('done'})
stream.on('error',function(err){console.log('Error')});
dumpFile.pipe(stream);
```

MySQL'd LOAD DATA INFILE appears to offer broadly similar functionality for copying from file, but it does not appear to have an option to use stdin in place of an actual file on the local file system. Also the node.js driver for MYSQL does not appear to have an equivalent of the pg-copy-stream module that enables copying a stream to the server.

Comment: I assume you are referring to `LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL` and I don't see anyone who has [requested this feature](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+LOCAL+INFILE). Might be worth requesting. I'd ask for it to be implemented as a callback rather than tieing it to a stream implementation.

Comment: @danblack. New to MySQL so I'm open to suggestions. The local option may meet my needs assuming I can use it from NODE.js, since in this case I will be simply creating a read stream on a file.. However if I have to do any pre-processing of the file before sending it the database a streamed based or callback would still be useful I think...

Comment: Using it without a general feature to take a non-file use will be a bit messy. The best alternative in the mean time I suggest is to transform the data in node.js into  the correct `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Unfortunately the file is simply one large block of JSON that I want to store as such...